# How to segue to another view controller when a subview with a gesture is tapped?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, xcode6

I have a view controller with a subview: gestureView that is referenced by the view controller via an outlet.  I have assigned a tap gesture from viewDidLoad of the parent view controller to gestureView like:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self.gestureView action:@selector(handleTap)];
[self.gestureView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
```

gestureView uses a custom class where handleTap: is implemented and it works fine, I can log from gestureView's handleTap:, however how can I perform a segue from the current view controller to another view controller when gestureView is tapped.

I understand that there may be easier ways to do this, but this works best for my situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **Delegate** pattern or **Notification** pattern.
Both will work in your case, As -handleTap() method is implemented in your subview you can create **protocol** in your **subview class**.
And when you get handleTap method you can call delegate method which should be implemented in your parent class.

In your subview class **Above class declaration** define protocol

```
@protocol SubViewClassDelegate <NSObject>
@required;
- (void) subviewDidTapped:(id) sender;
@end
```

Define property of delegate.

```
@property (nonatomic, unsafe_unretained) id<SubViewClassDelegate> delegate;
```

In implementation file of subview's class call delegate method.

```
- (void) handleTap   {
        if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(subviewDidTapped:)]) {
[self.delegate subviewDidTapped:yourObject]; // in yourObject you can pass data if require.
}
}
```

In your parent class implemented delegate of subview class

```
@interface ParentViewController : UIViewController <SubViewClassDelegate>
```

In **viewDidLoad**

```
self.gestureView.delegate = self;
```

And Implement the delegate method of Subview class in Parent controller.

```
-(void) subviewDidTapped:(id)sender {

 // Navigate using performSegueWithIdentifier:
[self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"segueIdentifier" sender: self];
 }
```

Comment: Can you modify you example to address the segue part if possible

Comment: I have added it, It was already given in answer by Raymon.
But I don't like to spoon feeding. Make a practice of doing simple things by own.

Answer (score 0):

In the `handleTap`, perform a segue to the other view controller you intend to display next.

```
 [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"YOU_SEGUE_IDENTIFIER" sender: self];
```

The segue that you will perform is the segue in the storyboard that is from current view controller to the next view controller. (You need to create this).

You can pass parameters on to the next view controller in the `prepareForSegue:sender:`, once you identify that it is the correct sender by checking the segue identifier.

Comment: This does not work because gestureView's custom class inherits from UIView which doesn't implement performSegueWithIdentifier.

Comment: Yah. Sorry bout that one. I've misread the UITapGestureRecognizer's initialization. Do you have any special processing that is special inside the gestureView, when the tap gesture is triggered?

You can set the target of the UITapGestureRecognizer to the parent view controller, and implement the handleTap method in the VC. Inside the VC's handleTap, you trigger the gestureView's own handleTap method